# Copy data from another workbook based on date range

Tags: excel, vba, date, copy

I am trying to copy the data from a "database" work book based on certain criteria on a user form.

It is getting caught in the first IF and always returning the message "no job started"
I made sure before I started copying based on criteria it would copy all data.

The goal is have it copy the data based on the range date range of textbox1 and textbox2 and then comboBox1.

I am stepping in to the range portions I traying to start with just one date.

```
 sub paste_values()
    
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim DateStart As String
Dim CurrentRow As Variant
    
    'open source workbook
    
    Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\115485\OneDrive - HUBBELL INC\Desktop\Labor tracking\database.xlsm"
    
    'copying our data
  
  'ws = Workbooks("database.xlsm").Sheets("database")
  DateStart = 6 / 21 / 22 'TextBox1.Value
  WC = ComboBox1.Value
  CurrentRow = Application.Match(DateStart, Workbooks("database.xlsm").Sheets("database").Range("E:E"), 0)
  If IsError(CurrentRow) Then
        MsgBox "No job started on that date."
  Else
    WC = Application.Match(DateStart, Workbooks("database.xlsm").Sheets("database").Range("A:A"), 0)
    If IsError(CurrentRow) Then
    MsgBox "No job completed at this WC."
    
    Else
    
    Workbooks("database.xlsm").Sheets("database").Range("A" & CurrentRow).Copy
    'define destination and paste values
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Efficiency").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    End If
End If
        
    'close and save source workbook
    Workbooks("database.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=True
    

End Sub


Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If TextBox1.Value = "" Then
   MsgBox "YOU DID NOT ENTER A DATE."
End If
Call paste_values

Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub
```

Comment: Put `6 / 21 / 22` in quotes?

Comment: How would I do it when I use the textbox1.value

Comment: If it's OK with you to write the date in the textbox1 with this kind of format, example : dec 25, 00 .... Jan 1,  22 ... jul 25, 64 (month name space date comma space year), then maybe you can try `DateStart = datevalue(TextBox1.Value)`